# Fabric.js gradients

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am building an app using **fabric.js** where user can customize some designs and I there is gradient option so that users can fill shapes with solid color and gradients, for now, I am providing simple 4 types of gradients and  users can only create gradients using two colors everything is working fine...but now i also need to include a slider so that user can also set from where to color start separating...but slider not working as expected I want that if slider is in middle then both colors are 50%.

[This is my gradient editing tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0PmF.png)

**And this is my code for applying gradients to shapes object**

```
function addGradientauto() {
color1=$('#gdcolorone').val();
color2=$('#gdcolortwo').val();
range=$('#gdrangesld').val();
range=parseFloat(range);
if(GD_type==null) {
    type=1;
}
else {
    type=GD_type;
}
rgb=gradhextorgba(color2);
rgba=rgb.replace(')', ', 0)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
rgba=rgba.replace(";", "");
if ($('#gradientalpha').is(':checked')) {
    color2=rgba;
}
obj=canvas.getActiveObject();
if (type==1) {
    obj.setGradient('fill', {
        type: 'linear', x1: 0, y1: obj.height, x2: 0, y2: obj.height / 4, colorStops: {
            range: color1, 1: color2
        }
    }
    );
}
else if(type==2) {
    obj.setGradient('fill', {
        type: 'linear', x1: obj.width, y1: 0, x2: obj.width / 4, y2: 0, colorStops: {
            range: color1, 1: color2
        }
    }
    );
}
else if (type==3) {
    obj.setGradient('fill', {
        type: 'linear', x1: 0, y1: obj.height / 4, x2: 0, y2: obj.height, colorStops: {
            range: color1, 1: color2
        }
    }
    );
}
else if (type==4) {
    obj.setGradient('fill', {
        type: 'linear', x1: obj.width / 4, y1: 0, x2: obj.width, y2: 0, colorStops: {
            range: color1, 1: color2
        }
    }
    );
}
canvas.renderAll();
save();
```

}